# Tesseract with NDK not working with Cygwin

Tags: android, android-ndk, cygwin

I am using the below link to run the code on windows xp. I have downloaded cygwin and android ndk 8
I am stuck at step 6 in the below link.

[OCR for android image to text](http://kurup87.blogspot.in/2012/03/android-ocr-tutorial-image-to-text.html)

Answer (score 0):

- you don't need Cygwin for the latest releases of the NDK
- you also should avoid using Cygwin for development purposes in every possible way
- that guide is wrong not only about Cygwin but also about the JDK version, the Android SDK requires the Oracle JDK 1.6, JDK 1.7 is not supported or required

You should read about the requirements for the Android tools and find a much better guide.

Comment: please help me i am stuck from morning on how to do this... i am new to android

Comment: @Goofy https://github.com/search?q=tesseract+android&repo=&langOverride=&start_value=1&type=Repositories&language= and before you ask, you can't find a tutorial about this without knowing at least the basics about Android and the programming world, before programming be sure that you have the basic know-how to do the job

Comment: @Ken i have some programming exp but even i tried executing this but how? i dont know how to proceed with step 6.

Comment: @Ken yes i agree with you you have mentioned cygwin is not required for android ndk 8 then how to proceed please help me on that

Comment: @Ken i found this also http://gaut.am/making-an-ocr-android-app-using-tesseract/ but again stuck there.

Comment: @Goofy trash that guide, follow one of the github repositories ( they also provide some examples ), learn about Android: you really have all the resources that you need here, this is not a tutorial website, i have provided more than a standard answer is supposed to provide, if you can't go forward it's because you need to acquire more skills, and you can't expect someone to do your job.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18171/discussion-between-goofy-and-ken)